# Download mp3 files from webpage

Tags: python

[This link](https://www.americanrhetoric.com/barackobamaspeeches.htm) includes some mp3 files which are speeches given by Barack Obama. I'd like to download these audio files, but I'll have to click into each mp3 file and download it one by one, which is quite tedious. Is it possible to do that using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://pypi.org/project/wget/ to download the webpage or files like mp3

Then parse the html content for hyperlinks, retrieve the hyperlink and then wget that link.

This may include a lot of parsing by inspecting element on browser of webpage you posted.

Heres what you are looking for, I have used python2.7 and shell for ease of use. Linux wget for linux was showing "ERROR 403: Forbidden" but python wget worked.

```
>>> # download the webpage
>>> import wget
>>> file = wget.download("https://www.americanrhetoric.com/barackobamaspeeches.htm")
100% [............................................................................] 522790 / 522790>>>
>>> file
u'barackobamaspeeches.htm'
>>>
```

Parse the downloaded file using grep and awk to extract links from it. If you are unaware of grep and awk please read about it.

```
$ ls
barackobamaspeeches.htm
$ grep "<a href" barackobamaspeeches.htm | grep mp3 | awk -F \" '{print $2}' > mp3_links
$ ls
barackobamaspeeches.htm  mp3_links
```

Now links are available, read them and use wget to download.

```
>>> # Read links from file in a list
>>> fd = open("mp3_links", "r")
>>> links = fd.read().splitlines()
>>> fd.close()
>>>
>>> # Create links for download by prepending base url
>>> base_link = 'https://www.americanrhetoric.com/'
>>> for link in links:
>>>     print(base_link + link)
>>>
>>> # replace print with wget.download(base_link + link)
```

I have tested it for single link, please try out and tweak the code accordingly

Comment: Could you give an example on how to parse, retrieve and wget the link? I have zero experience in using Python to obtain data from webpage so some code example would be really helpful.

Comment: @StevenChan I have updated my answer with code snippets, please have a look at it and let me know if it works for you or not?